# Application of Bochner's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying Besse's Einstein manifold, and in chapter 7 we have:
Theorem 7.56. Homogeneous Einstein manifold with negative scalar curvature implies $M,G$ are non compact.\

He says that this is a corollary of Bochner's theorem, so in this case I have that there are no non-zero killing vector fields and isometry group is finite, butso how can I conclude?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something stupid, but i can't see how i can conclude that $M$ and $G$ are non compact

Comment: Recall that you can identify the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ with Killing vector fields on $M = G/K$.